# Add same DefaultMutableTreeNode to 2 different DefaultMutableTreeNode

Tags: swing, jtree, defaultmutabletreenode

I have a **DefaultMutableTreeNode("birds")** which has n number of children. Now I want to add this node to 2 different parents **DefaultMutableTreeNode("animals")**  & **DefaultMutableTreeNodes("animals2")**.

But as the add or insert method of DefaultMutableTreeNode removes the child from it's parent first. The **DefaultMutableTreeNode("birds")** is getting added in only one of the parent node. Whichever is the called later.

Is there any way around this?

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode birds = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("birds");
DefaultMutableTreeNode animals = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("animals");
DefaultMutableTreeNode animals2 = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("animals2");
animals.add(birds);
animals2.add(birds);
```

Comment: No, it's not possible, because `DefaultMutableTreeNode` is used to represent trees, but in your case it's a graph. So you can only add a new node with the same text.

Comment: What's the solution then? Can I duplicate the node and then add it?How can I duplicate?

Comment: Something like this: `animals2.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("birds"));`

Comment: But that won't add the children of already existing birds node. I don't want to create new node with no children. I just want to add the node to another parent node. This seems so simple yet there is no explanation of it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up with below solution

`JTree.DynamicUtilTreeNode.createChildren(DefaultMutableTreeNode parent, Object children)
 JTree myTree = new JTree(parent)`

This takes a root node as input and children object can be either an array, vector or hashtable. I used hashtable initially to store all the tree's children(birds) and then added them to 2 different root nodes(animals & animals2).

Answer (score 1):

If I correct understand your problem the best way is to create a method which provides "birds-hierarchy":

```
private DefaultMutableTreeNode createBirdsNode() {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode birds = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("birds");
    // add another nodes to birds node.
    return birds;
}
```

And later you can use this method to add the complete hierarchy.

```
animals.add(createBirdsNode());
animals2.add(createBirdsNode());
```